# Ionic Facebook Plugin Error

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am trying to add the Facebook plugin (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) to my existing Ionic app, but I cannot get it to work.

I am currently getting the following when I include the plugin script:

> Can't find variable: require

Here's the script in my markup:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/master/facebookConnectPlugin.js"></script>
```

If I throw in a reference to requirejs (which I'm using later in the markup for bootstrapping the Angular + RequireJS part of my app), I end up with the following error:

> Module name "cordova/exec" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

See the ngCordova facebook plugin document
[ngCordova Facebook Plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/)

enjoy the program

Comment: Please add some content from the link.

Answer (score 1):

sample code=== 
first plugin install and then inject **$cordovaFacebook**  in controller and write some code below

```
$scope.facebook_login = function() {
         $cordovaFacebook.login(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"])
             .then(function(success) {
                 console.log('Arguments', arguments);
                 $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me", {
                     params: {
                         access_token: success.authResponse.accessToken,
                         fields: "id,name,gender,email,birthday",
                         format: "json"
                     }
                 }).then(function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                 }, function(error) {
                     console.log(error);
                 });
             }, function(error) {
                 console.log(error);
             });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand you need to install this plugin on your app. I don't see in install guid ability to include it from web. It should build some things and add some settings to cordova. Have you read this instruction?

[instruction on git](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/)